# GWT - image from database

Tags: java, database, image, gwt

I'm actually working on a GWT based website.
Now I'm stuck on how I should display images stored in a database on my website.

Basically I've a bytearray in my database, which I fetch using hibernate.
Now should I probably create an ... tag out of that data, but I don't know how

I'm using GWT in Java and Hibernate

Comment: +1 .. because every gwt developer will come accross to this problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is the solution. First you should encode the byte array by using com.google.gwt.user.server.Base64Utils.toBase64(byte[]) . But this method does not work for IE 7. and IE8 has 32kb limit.. IE9 does not have this limit.

here is the method on the server

```
public String getImageData(){
      String base64 = Base64Utils.toBase64(imageByteArray); 
      base64 = "data:image/png;base64,"+base64;
      return base64;
}
```

Here is the client method ;

```
@Override 
public void onSuccess(String imageData) {     
    Image image = new Image(imageData);     
    RootPanel.get("image").add(image); 
}
```

Comment: what is "image" means (what tag is that) in this call RootPanel.get("image"); and how to do the same in uibinders and action dispatch.

Comment: @Bennet `image` here is the id of div tag created in html page of gwt project.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how GWT works, albeit you can map a servlet/controller which returns resourceStream.
For example if you map a servlet "imageViewer" which takes imageId param, request to image would become

```
/imageViewer?imageId=1234
```

Hibernate object would have reference to the blob, so you can return that.
Reference on UI would be

```
<img src="/imageViewer?imageId=1234"/>
```

Update: You may not be able to use Model as it is to return image, you would need an explicit controller or servlet which returns stream data.
In servlet you would do something like

```
// get reference to input stream
InputStream in = hibnerateObject.getImage();  
// set MIME type etc
response.setContentType(mimeType);
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
while ((len = in.read(buf)) >= 0)
 out.write(buf, 0, len);
in.close();
out.close();
```

Comment: That one seems to be quite reasonable. In a "normal" JSP or PHP or whatever homepage you would have to do something like this too. Or?

Comment: You could make request from "browser", irrespective of view/templating technology. Its a simple HTTP request. It should work Ajax as well.

Comment: A great balusc's tutorial about serving images through servlets:
http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/04/imageservlet.html
This approach works with Image widget as well

Answer (score 1):

There is [Image Widget](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Image.html) in GWT. You can't do it client-side but you can call [RPC](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/DevGuideServerCommunication.html) to communicate with the server. Then it is simple CRUD application. In server connect to database with hibernate and return the Image to the client or it's url and on the client-side do something like that :

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(String imageUrl) {
    Image image = new Image(imageUrl);
    RootPanel.get("image").add(image);
}

@Override
public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
    Window.alert(caught.getMessage());
}
```

That's all. Happy coding

Comment: Okay, I knew about that widget, but it requires a URL, which I don't have, as it is an Image in a DB

Comment: you should get it and save it the disk (getBLOB) then give it's url to the image. Otherwise , I think you can't show the image I mean without coping it to the disk

Comment: >  I think you can't show the image I mean without coping it to the disk - Yes you can show the image without copying it on the disk. All you need to do is return blob back to the UI.

Answer (score 1):

I used the same approach as Gursel Koca suggested but could only get it to work using the Apache Base64 library, not (ironically) the GWT Base64Utils

```
String base64 = Base64.encodeBase64String(array);
base64 = "data:image/"+type+";base64," + base64;
return base64;
```

Also note that if you are updating an existing image or an image placeholder, the setURL method will overwrite your stylesheet, so make sure to grab that first:

```
String styleName = profilePicture.getStyleName();
profilePicture.setUrl(base64String);
profilePicture.setStyleName(styleName);
```